# How to fix checkov failed item by its rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, terraform, amazon-iam, policy

When run checkov for an Terraform resource scan, got this failed

```
Check: CKV_AWS_111: "Ensure IAM policies does not allow write access without constraints"
    FAILED for resource: aws_iam_policy_document.foo
    File: /data.tf:7-18

    data "aws_iam_policy_document" "foo" {
      statement {
        effect = "Allow"
        actions = [
          "cloudwatch:Describe*",
          "cloudwatch:Get*",
          "cloudwatch:List*",
          "sns:Subscribe",
        ]
        resources = ["*"]
      }
    }
```

From official document, found its [introduction
page](https://docs.bridgecrew.io/docs/ensure-iam-policies-do-not-allow-write-access-without-constraint).

There is a `Fix - Buildtime` on the page, but how to refer it to use for my
case?

From its
[Resource
Exposure](https://cloudsplaining.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary/resource-exposure/)
on the page,
I didn't find any name in the `"Resource Exposure" actions` list as `cloudwatch` or `sns`, why it failed?

If fix it without add a `# checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_111: XXXX`, how to do to adjust
the `data` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the wild card with resources, Right now it's opened widely for all the resources.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "foo" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "cloudwatch:Describe*",
      "cloudwatch:Get*",
      "cloudwatch:List*",
      "sns:Subscribe",
    ]
    resources = ["resource-arn"]
  }
}
```

If you change the resource's wild card to the list of arns of the resources, which will use this policy then checkov will not show this error anymore.